# JavaFX Stage shows always empty scene

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder

Using:

- IntelliJ IDEA community ide.
- Java JDK 9.0.1
- Scene builder 9.0.1

I always get empty scene.

Here is the fxml file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>


<GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" fx:controller="view.Controller">
   <children>
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

Here is the main class code:

```
package view;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
        primaryStage.show();

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to work okay for me (not using Intellij), maybe do a clean and build?

Comment: What OS/window manager do you use?

Comment: @CrazyCoder windows 10 64bit

Comment: Try a more recent Java version, like Java 10.

Comment: Do you get any error messages about the controller ? Try removing `fx:controller="view.Controller`

Comment: Also for `Gridpane` you want to remove `<children>` tag and use `<Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button"  GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0"/>`

Comment: @c0der Why remove the `<children>` tag? It is the default property, but imho it's better to include it nontheless. Also assigning the `columnIndex` and `rowIndex` should not fix anything here, since `GridPane` treats non-set indices as `0`.

Comment: Assuming IntellIJ does does not screw around with JavaFX in some unexpected way, the only thing that could go wrong is some weird code in the `Controller.initialize` method...

Comment: @fabian as for "why" I follow the official an oracle [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/fxml_tutorial.htm). It is not proposed as a remedy to the problem.  A possible remedy to the problem appears in the previous comment : "Do you get any error messages about the controller ? Try removing `fx:controller="view.Controller` "

Comment: @c0der An exception in creating or initializing the controller would result in that exception being propagated to the `start()` method; and uncaught exceptions in the `start()` method terminate the application. So the OP would not see an empty scene in this case; no window would be displayed at all.